# What if main method is made parameterized, then how one can specify its real type?

Tags: java, generics, generic-method

```
public class TestA {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> void main(String...args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("--Parent--");
        final InheritableThreadLocal<T> itl = new InheritableThreadLocal<T>() {
            @Override
            protected T childValue(T i)
            {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\r\n" + i );
                return i;

            }
        };

        itl.set((T) new Integer(33));

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread.currentThread().setName("--local--");
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\r\n" + itl.get());

            }
        };

        new Thread(r).start();
        System.out.println(itl.get());
    }
}
```

So how can I specify a type here. 
As no type is specified in above mentioned code so default Object type is in picture. I want to make local inner class "InheritableThreadLocal" generic.

Comment: Why making it generic in the first place?

Comment: Just so I can get advantage of generics and type safety. I could use inner local with pre-specified type <Integer> instead of <T>. But now I am curious- how to make this work. So if you guys can help me out here.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Due to type erasure the code behaves exactly the same at run-time regardless of what the "real type" of `T` is. Therefore, there's no point in specifying any type for T. You don't need the `main` method to be generic at all. `itl.set((T) new Integer(33));` implies that you should be using `Integer` in place of `T`.

Comment: @davmac you are right, but soul of question is- if there is any way to make main method parameterized. I have never seen such case, so if you can please comment on this. Code is just a sample to present this picture.

Comment: @Manoj you _have_ made the main method parameterized. But there is no point to doing so, neither with the code sample you have provided nor at all. See Stephen C.'s answer.

Comment: Fair enough... so we can't specify and anyway it doesn't affect anything, so yes that answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

> So how can I specify a type here.

You can't.

Or at least ... you can't specify a type if the `main` method is used as the application entry point method when launching a JVM.

However, it doesn't really matter:

- Since generics are implemented using type erasure, the `main` method code can't tell what the real type of `T` is anyway.
- Since the method can't tell, it doesn't matter what it is.

---

Note that in your example, the only place where `T` is "used" is in the type cast `(T)`.  If you remove the `@SuppressWarning` annotations, the compiler will tell you that the type cast is an unchecked conversion; i.e. it doesn't do anything.

You will find that this is the same that for any other (compilable) example of a generic `main` that you can write.  Basically, there is no way to write a generic `main` where the type parameters actually matter.

---

Notes:

1. The JLS does not state that a `main` entry point method cannot have type parameters; see [JLS 12.1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4).
2. A trivial Java application with a parameterized `main` compiles without errors, and runs without errors.